# How to apply rtrim function in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, array-map

I have an array like that

```
Array
(
    [1] => Hollywood » 
    [2] => 3D Animation » Hollywood » 
    [3] => Natural Beauty » Hollywood » 3D Animation » 
    [4] => Song » Hollywood » 
    [5] => Car » Hollywood » 3D Animation » 
    [6] => Folk Song » Hollywood » Song » 
    [7] => Modern Song » Hollywood » Song » 
)
```

Now I want to remove the last `&raquo;(>>)`. I think it can be done by `rtrim` function

Example

```
rtrim("Modern Song » Hollywood » Song »", "&raquo;");
```

Now How can I apply `rtrim` in array without any loop.

I have try that but I dont know how to pass the second parameter in `rtrim` function

```
$restult = array_map('rtrim', $arrData);
```

I also try that

```
$restult = array_map('rtrim', $arrData, '&raquo;');
```

But third parameter have to be array

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Hollywood
        [2] => 3D Animation » Hollywood
        [3] => Natural Beauty » Hollywood » 3D Animation
        [4] => Song » Hollywood
        [5] => Car » Hollywood » 3D Animation
        [6] => Folk Song » Hollywood » Song 
        [7] => Modern Song » Hollywood » Song
    )
```

Solution in `cakephp` way is preferred.

Comment: Create a `function rtrimRaquo($v) {return rtrim($v, "&raquo;")}` and pass its name to `array_map`: `array_map("rtrimRaquo", $arrData)`.

Comment: Yes I already try this but how can I implement in `cakephp`

Comment: Someone give an answer and that was right. when I'm going to accept that answer I fount that it was deleted. I don't know why he delete answer. anyway Thank him to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
$arr = [
    'Hollywood » ',
    '3D Animation » Hollywood » ',
    'Natural Beauty » Hollywood » 3D Animation » ',
    'Song » Hollywood » ',
];

function trimRaquo($what) {
    return rtrim($what," »");
}

$arr2 = array_map('trimRaquo',$arr);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arr2);
echo '</pre>';
```

I'm not sure why but when I leave out the extra space at the left of the symbol: `"»"` instead of `" »"` the function will not be applied. I'd hazard it's because `" »" !== "»"` and `rtrim()` looks for exact matches.

also writing `"&raquo;"` does not seem to work, either in single or double quotes, hence of my use of the character `"»"`

I don't know cakephp, but this the use of such fundamental functions is very much framework agnostic...

Answer (score 0):

Used `array_map` to apply the `rtrim` function to each element in the array, removing the trailing `&raquo;` and any extra spaces. The resulting array will have the updated values without the trailing characters

```
$data = [
    1 => 'Hollywood »',
    2 => '3D Animation » Hollywood »',
    3 => 'Natural Beauty » Hollywood » 3D Animation »',
    4 => 'Song » Hollywood »',
    5 => 'Car » Hollywood » 3D Animation »',
    6 => 'Folk Song » Hollywood » Song »',
    7 => 'Modern Song » Hollywood » Song »',
];

// Remove the trailing » from each element in the array
$result = array_map(function ($item) {
    return rtrim($item, '» ');
}, $data);

print_r($result);
```